# Returning pointer from function after being initialized to non-local pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scope

I think what I'm doing is safe but I want to check with all you smart people first.

I know returning a pointer to a local variable from a function is bad!

But what if a pointer is allocated outside of a function call and passed in as input. Then inside the function call a local pointer is made, initialized to the input pointer, used to set some `struct->members`, and then `return`ed?

Here's an example using `(int *)` instead of my code's `(struct type_s *)`:

```
int *modify_p_x(int *p_x)
{
    int *new_p_x = p_x;
    *new_p_x = 100;
    return new_p_x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 42;
    int *p_x = &x;

    p_x = modify_p_x(p_x);

    return 0;
}
```

Since `new_p_x is` initialized using `p_x` and `p_x` has a lifetime irrespective of the`modify_p_x` function call, does that make this code safe?

Thanks.

Comment: This is no code review site! Did you experience any problems with that code? (looks ok to me). Note **always** enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Your original premise is already wrong. "I know returning local pointers from a function is bad"? Who told you that? There's noting inherently bad with "returning local pointers". In fact, it is completely irrelevant whether the pointer itself is local or not. The only thing that matters is how "local" is the object *the pointer is pointing to*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say returning a pointer to a local variable. After returning from the function the local variable does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with local pointers; the problem is with returning a pointer to a local *thing*.  Recall *why* this is bad: when the function returns, the memory used by that thing can be re-used for other things.

`modify_p_x` is given a pointer to `x` (allocated in `main`), uses it to change `x`, and returns that pointer, which `main` then re-assigns to `p_x`.  Except for how it is used, this is no different than if you were using `int`s instead of pointers, and I don't think you ever worried about returning an `int` variable.